# Getting Custom Post Type Meta on Publish

Tags: custom-post-types, metabox

Can you please take a look at this code and let me know why I am not able to get the Custom Post Meta on publishing the post. I tried thses

```
function get_cpt_meta($post_ID) {
 $post = get_post($post_ID);
 $meta = get_post_custom(); 
         $mfname = $meta['f_name'][0];
         $mlname = $meta['l_name'][0];
         echo $mfname. " " . $mlname;
}
add_action('publish_book', 'get_cpt_meta');
```

and

```
function get_cpt_meta($post_ID) {
 $post = get_post($post_ID);
 $meta = get_post_custom($post); 
         $mfname = $meta['f_name'][0];
         $mlname = $meta['l_name'][0];
         echo $mfname. " " . $mlname;
}
add_action('publish_book', 'get_cpt_meta');
```

Comment: WP has some hooks where the post itself (`prefix_posts` table) has been published or updated, but the postmeta (`prefix_postmeta` table) has not yet been inserted. You may want to look into another hook such as `save_post`. It fires multiple times, but if you check for your desired status (publish) and the presence of `$_POST[]` data in that hook, there will be one run of the hook where the postmeta is present.

Comment: Thanks for reply but how can I bind this hook with Custom Post type? I mean in `publish_` hook I pass the `book` as a post like `publish_book` but what about the `save_post`?

Comment: `save_post` fires on all post types, so you would check inside your function to verify that this is a `book` post type, and the status is `publish`, and there is `$_POST[]` data - and then do whatever you want with the postmeta.

Comment: so something like this is fine `if ($post->post_type ==  'book'  ){ // Get terms}` ?

Comment: Yes, along those lines - but probably a little more complex. `if($post->post_type == 'book' && $post->post_status == 'publish' && !empty($_POST)) { // Get terms }`